# Navigation drawer with bottom navigation

Tags: android-layout

In my application i want a navigation drawer with bottom navigation menu, but problem is that my container(content page) is overlapping the bottom navigation bar , i have attached my layout code with this question, please can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tunky.cardmaterial.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            tools:openDrawer="start">


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/card_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/message"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>


            <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: my experience is: the drawer layout should place at the outmost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/navigation">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```